# Prove $g(x) = x^3$ is continuous at $x_0$ arbitrary

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We are proving $g(x) = x^3$ is continuous at $x_0$ arbitrary.

- My attempt:

For all $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for an arbitrary point $x_0$ and $ \lvert x - x_0 \rvert \lt \delta \implies \lvert g(x) - g(x_0) \rvert \lt \epsilon$.

We plug in $g(x) = x^3$ to get:

$ \lvert x - x_0 \rvert \lt \delta \implies \lvert x^3 - x_0^3 \rvert \lt \epsilon$.

But we recognize $\lvert x^3 - x_0^3 \rvert = \lvert x - x_0 \rvert \lvert x^2 + x_0x + x_0^2 \rvert \lt \lvert x- x_0 \rvert \lvert x^2 + 2xx_0 + x_0^2 \rvert = \lvert x - x_0 \rvert \lvert (x+ x_0)^2 \rvert \lt \epsilon$.

So we have $ \lvert x^3 - x_0^3 \rvert \lt \lvert x-x_0 \rvert \lvert x+x_0 \rvert \lvert x+x_0 \rvert $

I'm not sure how to choose the proper relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how you can make that claim unless $x_0 = 0$ or $x = 0$.

Comment: Wow, nevermind I just understood why haha

Comment: Generally $|x-x_0|\ne|x+x_0|$.

Comment: Try this: $|x+x_0|\le|2x_0|+|x-x_0|$

Comment: Your inequality $|x-x_0||x^2+xx_0+x_0^2| < |x-x_0||x^2+2xx_0+x_0^2|$ is incorrect since $xx_0$ could be negative.  You can replace it with $|x-x_0||x^2 + xx_0 + x_0^2| \leq |x-x_0||x^2 + 2|x||x_0| + x_0^2| = |x-x_0|(|x_0|+|x|)^2$.

Comment: Also, your initial structure of the proof is confusing.  You want to start by fixing $x_0$ and $\epsilon>0$, then defining a particular $\delta>0$.  Then say "Suppose $|x-x_0|\leq \delta$.  We want to show $|g(x)-g(x_0)|\leq \epsilon$."  Usually you will only know what $\delta$ to choose at the END of the proof (when you have completed your calculations), but you can make the proof non-chronological by then going back and putting that $\delta$ at the top.  Or you can end the proof just by saying "note that usign $\delta$ of this size makes hte desired thing less than or equal to $\epsilon$.

Comment: In other (shorter) words:  Your first sentence "For all $\epsilon>0$...$|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |g(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$" is what you want to prove.  It does not make sense, in the course of your proof, to "plug in" to something that you want to prove, since that has not yet been proven!

Comment: Don't know if these comments are helpful or not.  Anyway, note that the  @MarioCarneiro comment shows how to choose $\delta$ as a function of $x_0$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, if i used  |x+x0|≤|2x0|+|x−x0|, could i just set $\delta = \epsilon^\frac1 3 - 2x_0$?

Comment: Well I will answer:  "No" because what if $2x_0>\epsilon^{1/3}$?  On the other hand, notice that, if we started out assuming that $|x-x_0|\leq \delta$ (hint, hint, you should start by assuming this), then we could conclude that $|2x_0| + |x-x_0| \leq |2x_0|+\delta$.

Comment: @Michael, great answer! How would we incorporate that inequality into the inequality involving $\epsilon$? I'm having a hard time making the relation between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ in this specific problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working from the starting point $|x^3-x_0^3|\le|x-x_0||x+x_0|^2\le\delta(2|x_0|+\delta)^2$ would suggest choosing $\delta=\min(\frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0|+1},1)$ but one of the comment points out that you made an inequality error when changing $xx_0$ to $2xx_0$. Instead, you can use $|x|\le|x_0|+|x-x_0|$ to get

$$|x^2+xx_0+x_0^2|\le(\delta+|x_0|)^2+\delta|x_0|+|x_0|^2=\delta^2+3\delta|x_0|+2|x_0|^2,$$

so $|x^3-x_0^3|\le\delta(\delta^2+3\delta|x_0|+2|x_0|^2)$ and you can pick $\delta=\min(\dfrac\epsilon{1+3|x_0|+2|x_0|^2},1)$.

---

Alternatively, you could just ignore the whole mess by noting that the product of continuous functions is continuous, so $x^3=x\cdot x\cdot x$ is continuous since $x$ is (choose $\delta=\epsilon$).

Comment: Just curious why you say to choose $\delta = \epsilon$. How are you able to say that so quickly without doing any work? I want to get to the point where I can make those kinds of statements immediately just by looking at the problem.

Comment: @DavidSouth Because it's the identity function: If I want $|x-x_0|<\delta\to|x-x_0|<\epsilon$, obviously $\delta=\epsilon$ will do the trick. But that's sort of a special case...

Comment: @DavidSouth In this case, you should note that the two examples I gave (for the two inequality calculations) give a general algorithm for picking $\delta$ if you can derive an inequality like $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le\delta g(\delta)$ where $g$ is nonnegative and increasing and $g(1)>0$ - just choose $\delta=\min(\epsilon/g(1),1)$.